# Bash: How can I move all the content in the folder up to one level?

Tags: bash, move

How can I move the whole folder of _vim  into ~/.vim?

```
$ mv ~/.vim/_vim/ ~/.vim
mv: `/home/kithokit/.vim/_vim/' and `/home/kithokit/.vim/_vim' are the same file
```

I cannot do that.
Basically what I want to do is just move all the contents inside `_vim` folder up to one level, which is in `~/.vim/`

Comment: Not a programming question - belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
mv ~/.vim/_vim/* ~/.vim
```

Bash expands the `*` such the command now reads

```
mv ~/.vim/_vim/file_1 ... ~/.vim/_vim/file_n ~/.vim
```

Comment: This will skip dot files (like ".config").

Comment: @Dunes Exactly, it will not move _all_ directory content (as was requested). I think that worth mentioning.

Comment: @wonder.mice using `mv {,.}* will fix that. You will get an error message about trying to move `.` and `..` though. (I misread your first comment as "Will this" rather than "This will"). Deleted the original comment and post this new comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be careful to move hidden dotfiles as well as regular, visible files, and also not to clobber any files already in `~/.vim/`, then do this:

```
for A in $( find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ~/.vim/_vim ) ; do B=$( basename $A ) ; mv -iv ~/.vim/_vim/$B ~/.vim/ ; done
```

Most likely, you will wish to follow that with `rmdir ~/.vim/_vim`.

See also @Dunes' suggestions in the comments below.

Comment: You can use xargs to make the command simpler. `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ~/.vim/_vim | xargs mv -iv -t ~/.vim/`. You may also wish to use `-u` instead of `-i`.

Comment: @Dunes: That's cool.  I hadn't known about the `-t` option, and it has been ten years since I last used `xargs`.  I like it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ mv ~/.vim/_vim/* ~/.vim/
$ rmdir ~/.vim/_vim
```